# css display:inline does not work on <li> element

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul class="nav-dots">
  <li class='ni n1'><a href="" class='nia'>dot</a></li>
  <li class='ni n2'><a href="" class='nia'>dot</a></li>
  <li class='ni n3'><a href="" class='nia'>dot</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.nav-dots {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see, the `<li>` elements should display inline, but, they don't, and I have no idea why. How can I fix this?

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsexLf88/1/)

Comment: But you're not applying it to any `<li>` elements -- just the parent `<ul>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.nav-dots` is a `class` added to the parent `ul`. You need to call `display: inline;` on the `li`s themselves

```
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bsexLf88/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
.nav-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.ni {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Your CSS is applying the inline-block display property to the ul, not the li children

Answer (score 0):

also

```
.ni{display:inline}
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

`display` is not a property that is inherited. In order to keep the same structure you have and make the list items inline, you have to explicitly set their display property to `inherit`:

`li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inherit;
}`

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gLus6uL2/)**